# Is Windows Update deleting Sticky Notes (StikyNot.exe)?

Tags: windows-7, sticky-notes

I got a Windows 7 computer for Christmas and I like the Sticky Notes application. But twice now, the sticky notes have disappeared after an automatic Windows Update. I managed to navigate system restore and recover them, but it was a pain.

The update seems to be deleting StikyNot.exe, but I haven't been able to find any info on why.
Has anyone else experienced this?  Any ideas how to prevent it from happening again?

Comment: System Restore only restores the Registry, it does not restore deleted files. It'd be surprising an update deletes the executable and a System Restore puts it back.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why this is happening, but you can backup the Windows 7 Sticky Notes by backing up this file to another location :
`%AppData%\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\StickyNotes.snt`
which is normally:
`C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\StickyNotes.snt`.

You may have to show hidden/system files via the Folder Options.

Comment: Thanks but the data has been OK, so far.  I probably should look into backing it up...